# Apache Stanbol and (Semantic) Media Wiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantics, jcr, cmis, apache-stanbol

Is it possible to extend Media Wiki with semantic services using Apache Stanbol?
The [Stanbol Website](http://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/components/cmsa) indicates that "any content repository compliant with JCR or CMIS specifications" can be used.  However, I could not find whether this is the case for (Semantic) Media Wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually both JCR and CMIS are protocols much more popular on Java environments. As far as I know MediaWiki does not support any of them.

However, you can still use Stanbol via its RESTful interfaces.